# Cookie with different path value not present in Request.Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I'm creating a MVC version of an old ASP web app and I need reuse the existing cookies so that users don't have to reconfigure their settings in the MVC version. Most of the cookies have a path value of / but others have a path value of /scripts. The ones with the /scripts path value are not contained in Request.Cookies.

Can anyone know how I could access and update the /scripts cookies in a controller? I'm fairly new to MVC by the way.

Ideally i'd like a server side solution but if its not possible then a client side solution should be workable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those got to this question wondering why a POST request doesn't have your cookies on c# server-side. Cookies are stored relative to the path given and can only see that cookie in the Request for any children paths.

So if my page has a route `[Route("/Home/Dashboard/{id:int}")]` then the AJAX request also needs to be relative to that route.

e.g.

JavaScript:

```
// Set the Cookie
$.post("/Home/Dashboard/1/SaveMyThing", { myValue: "myValue" });

// Get the Cookie
$.post("/Home/Dashboard/1/DoMyThing");
```

C# (.NET CORE 3.1)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Home/Dashboard/{id:int}/SaveMyThing")]
public ActionResult SaveMyThing(int id, string myValue) {
    Response.Cookies.Append("myKey", myValue, new CookieOptions {
        Path = $"/Home/Dashboard/{id}"
    });
    return Ok();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/Home/Dashboard/{id:int}/DoMyThing")]
public ActionResult DoMyThing(int id) {
    ProcessMyThing(Request.Cookies["myKey"]);
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Server Side code to Get and Set Cookies :
        public void SetCookie(string key, string value, TimeSpan expires)
        {
            var encodedCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);

            encodedCookie.HttpOnly = true;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key] != null)
            {
                var cookieOld = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
                cookieOld.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
                cookieOld.Value = encodedCookie.Value;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieOld);
            }
            else
            {
                encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
            }
        }

        public string GetCookie(string key)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                // For security purpose, we need to encrypt the value.
                HttpCookie decodedCookie = cookie;
                value = decodedCookie.Value;
            }
            return value;
        }




Client Side code to Get and Set cookies

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Ganesh. This is very similar to what I have currently. My problem is that the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` collection does not contain the cookies with the path /scripts. It only contains the cookies with the path /

Is there a way to specify the path you want to use when requesting cookies? It always seems to default to /